# How to connect Eloquent to SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to connect Eloquent to my SQL Server DB.
But it keeps throwing me `QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] unrecognized msgno (localhost) (severity 11) (SQL: select top 1 * from [groups] where [groups].[id] = -6)`
I've tried executing this query and got `SQL Error [208] [S0002]`
Then I rewrote this query to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [db].[schema].[groups] WHERE [db].[schema].[groups].[id] = -6
```

and it executed correctly. After that I think that my configuration may be incorrect.
Here is my Eloquent/Capsule configuration:

```
[
      "driver"    => "sqlsrv",
      "host"      => "localhost",
      "database"  => "[db].[schema]",
      "username"  => "sa",
      "password"  => "dbpass",
      "charset"   => "utf8",
      "collation" => "",
      "prefix"    => "",
];
```

SQL Server Version: `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (CTP2.2) - 15.0.1200.24 (X64) Dec  5 2018 16:51:26 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Linux (KDE neon)`
Eloquent version: `5.6.28`
PHP Version: `7.2.10`

Comment: Is the host machine windows or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name your database name `"[db].[schema]",`

Use the name of the database you're actually using.
If your database is named InfinteCarrots use

Also, have the host `np:DOMAINNAME\SQLEXPRESS`

```
"driver"   => "sqlsrv",
"host"      => "np:EEBOFFICE\\SQLEXPRESS";
"database"  => "InfiniteCarrots",
```

These are the connection details I use at this moment to connect with SQL server on a windows server.
If you are connecting to a remote server you will want to use the domain name for it and have the connection set up to use encryption always.

```
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'example.com',
        'port'     => 1433,
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'username' => 'database_user',
        'password' => 'database_password',
```

Comment: But how do I specify schema then?

Comment: You don't need to. Just keep stuff in one schema dbo for your laravel tables

Comment: You specify the schema, if you want a different one other than `dbo`, in your model: `protected $table = 'schema.users'`